# How to set different page styles (as in Format - Page...) for individual pages in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I use `Format - Page - Background` to set background pictures for my pages. And I'd like one background picture for the first page and a different picture for the other pages. Some times I'd also like different margin settings for different pages. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

It's a lot harder than it has to be. First, you need to define a Page Style for each background image you want. These can be created in *View / Styles and Formatting / Page Styles [button]*. Right-click the list of page styles, click *New*, then name it in *the *Organization* tab. Make sure *Next Style* returns to *Default*. In the Background* tab, apply the color or graphic of your choice.

The key to having a different style on each page is the page break. Select *Insert / Manual Break / Page Brea*k. Under the style dropdown, select the Page Style/background you want the next page to have.

You can return to the first page (default white) and simply double-click on the page style you want. You can also do this for later pages for which the page break/style action has been done.

If you should want to apply a page style to the remainder of the document, modify or create a new page style, and in the organization tab, select the style you want in the *Next Style* dropdown.